Is there a way to simply remove all my comments from Politcs SE?
I would like to remain a user on this site and if possible retain my reputation points. I am not comfortable with the recent discourse.
Is there simple way to remove all of my presence without removing me as a user?
Several people have been abusive towards me when I asked simple questions. I was even accused of being a low reputation multi site harasser.
Thank you in advance for your help

If you intend to delete your questions and answers too, you should note that a) you will not keep the reputation points you gained from them, and b) users are rate-limited to deleting 5 questions or answers per day, to prevent users from rage-quitting and deleting all their contributions.

Regarding your claims of "abusive" behaviour: if you believe that other users have broken the Code of Conduct, you can flag their posts or comments for moderator attention, or use the "Contact" form linked at the bottom of the page. be sure to explain in as much detail as possible what CoC violation(s) you believe have occurred.

For the record, I can see no such abusive behaviour or allegations of harassment anywhere on your Stack Exchange profile, so it seems they have already been dealt with by the moderators.

@F1Krazy  While I each appriciate each of your comments, I am not rage quiting. I want to remain a member. I've read Q/A for years and for the most part others had already had answered or I didn't have an answer.

@F1Krazy Would I have been notified if a an interaction was deleted by a moderator? Because as you said, they are missing. That includes my questions to understand viewpoints as well. Does that mean a moderator decided that I was out of line? I haven't received any notifications.

"Would I have been notified if a an interaction was deleted by a moderator?" No, sadly not. "That includes my questions to understand viewpoints as well." If you were responding to comments that have been deleted, then your comments will have been deleted just to tidy up the comment thread and not leave orphaned responses, not because they broke any rules. If the moderators haven't contacted you via mod message, you can reasonably assume that you're not in any trouble.

@F1Krazy Thank you for the info. Have a good day.

On your user page, select "All actions" then select "Comments".
This will display a list of each of your active comments.
You could select the comments and delete them one at a time.

Thank you, I will do as advised.
